# Error ejecutando aplicación de flutter con VSCode

Tags: android, flutter, gradle

Estoy utilizando flutter para el desarrollo de aplicaciones en android y al crear el proyecto y ejecutarlo para ver como se ve en el emulador sale este error:

```
Launching lib\main.dart on Samsung Galaxy S9 in debug mode...
* Error running Gradle:
ProcessException: Process 
"E:\WorkSpaceFlutter\password_storage\android\gradlew.bat" exited abnormally:

Command: E:\WorkSpaceFlutter\password_storage\android\gradlew.bat app:properties

Please review your Gradle project setup in the android/ folder.
Exited (sigterm)
```

¿Esto se puede deber a que mi región esta bloqueada para descargar alguna dependencia o algo? O hay otra una forma de solucionarlo.
Gracias de ante mano.

Comment: Podrías añadir más información de la aplicación que intentas correr.

Comment: Es la aplicación de ejemplo nada más crear un nuevo proyecto.

Comment: Te muestra algun error al correr ```flutter doctor``` en la consola.

Comment: Error ninguno solo warning con Andoid studio por que no lo tengo instalado y warning con algo del certificado de android o algo así, no recuerdo bien. Pero ningun error.

Comment: Talvez ese warning es porque no aceptas la licencia de java corre este comando ```flutter doctor --android-licenses```, sino funciona intenta actualizar flutter con ```flutter upgrade``` a ver que pasa.

Comment: Ok probaré eso. Otra cosa, también es que tengo que usar vpn para poder descargar flutter. Y me parece que a la hora de correr el proyecto el descargará alguna dependencia no sé si estaré en lo correcto.